# Django - How to update a parent model using a child model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a two models something like this:

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
  id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, null=True)

class Child(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', related_name="parent_child", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, null=True)
```

If the parent quantity is different from the sum of the child quantities,
Updates the parent quantity to the sum of the child quantities.

I tried to get an object whose parent quantity is different from the sum of the child quantities:

```
parent = Parents.objects.annotate(sum_quantities=Sum('parent_child__quantity')).exclude(quantity=F('sum_quantities'))
```

It works! But I'm having trouble updating this.
Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
Parent.objects.annotate(
    sum_quantities=Sum('parent_child__quantity')).exclude(quantity=F('sum_quantities')).update(
        quantity=Subquery(
            Parent.objects.filter(parent=OuterRef('id')).annotate(sum_quantities=Sum('parent_child__quantity')).values('sum_quantities')[:1]    
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).